# как закрыть браузер при помощи javascript или jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

делаю таймер и хотелось бы, чтобы когда таймер заканчивался, закрывался браузер. Возможно ли это? знаю, что можно закрыть текущую вкладку методом close(), но это не то

Comment: нет, так сделать нельзя

Comment: Нет нельзя. Это противоречит элементарным требованиям безопасности например.

Comment: ну, ладно :((((

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, ответы в ответы.

Comment: @Qwertiy но это же идиотский ответ, хоть и подходит под него

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, это правильный ответ на нормальный вопрос.

Comment: @Qwertiy ну что-то такое не пойми что написал

Answer (score 4):

Меня заставили написать ответ :-/

Сделать то, что вы хотите на *js* нельзя. Как вариант, написанный @Утка Учится Уму -  это противоречит элементарным требованиям безопасности например.

Простой пример с приколюхой, если бы такое было возможно: представьте, заходите в поисковик, что-то ищите, кликаете на выданную ссылку, попадаете на незнакомый сайт и...он закрывает весь браузер. Как ощущение? А теперь вы запускаете браузер, но т.к. браузер закрылся с той вкладкой, он опять закрывается. Прекрасно, правда? Помогут либо танцы с бубном, либо переустановка браузера. Просто замечательная игра в сапёра - угадай сколько ссылок убьют браузер.

Comment: Эм.. Вообще-то, полагаю, что подразумевалось закрытие вкладки, а не браузера... Но спасибо что объяснил, что же именно все имеют в виду под проблемами с безопасностью.

Comment: @Qwertiy ну не знааааю.. вопрос написан так: "хочу чтобы когда таймер заканчивался, закрывался **браузер**.....знаю, что можно закрыть **текущую вкладку** методом **close()**, но **это не то** ))  Если я опять не на то ответил - то добавь свой ответ))

Comment: Метод `close` уже давно не работает. Его можно использовать только на том, что ты сам открыл через `open`. Да и то с ограничениями.

Comment: @Qwertiy я цитату привел чтоб указать то, что, всё же, имелся в виду браузер...вроде.  Про метод close я молчу)

Comment: помню когда-то была такая штука в винде, называлась con/con. ставишь ее в загрузку/ссылку и винда кидает синий экран. но это было еще ... в 95/98 винде. Точно не помню.